# when and how to use return & print while inter-calling the functions with if __name__ == '__main__': method

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a doubt, when and how to use return & print while inter-calling the functions with `if __name__ == '__main__':`  method.

For example i have quoted two example codes below the first one while i have used the `return` keyword into the First Fuction `CheckUid(user)` and print into second Function `CallUid()` , So When i ran the programm it runs and gives the ouput but the only the diffrence i see when `userid.txt` is being called to read the user ID's against the ldapsearch command and if user id doesn't exits then it returns `None` while otherhand while using the `print` statement into the First Fuction `CheckUid()` itself then calling it into second function `CallUid()` then it doesn't return `None` statement.

Please, suggest how and where to use `return` keyword while using the `if __name__ == '__main__':` method.

```
$ cat function1.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

def CheckUid(user):
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ldapsearch -h server1  -D 'cn=directory manager' -w pass123 -LLLb 'ou=people,o=rraka.com'  'uid=%s' managerlogin" % (user), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
    split_str = info_str.split()
    if len(split_str) > 1:
      return {'UserID': split_str[1].split(',')[0].split('=')[1], 'MangerID': split_str[-1]}
    else:
      split_str = 'null'

 def CallUid():
      with open('userid.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
         print(CheckUid(line))
         #return CheckUid(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CallUid()
```

> output as below:

```
$ ./function1.py
None
None
{'UserID': 'aashishp', 'MangerID': 'rpudota'}
{'UserID': 'abaillie', 'MangerID': 'davem'}
{'UserID': 'abishek', 'MangerID': 'kalyang'}
```

> While Other way around:

```
$ cat function2.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

def CheckUid(user):
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ldapsearch -h server1  -D 'cn=directory manager' -w pass123 -LLLb 'ou=people,o=rraka.com'  'uid=%s' managerlogin" % (user), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
    split_str = info_str.split()
    if len(split_str) > 1:
      print({'UserID': split_str[1].split(',')[0].split('=')[1], 'MangerID': split_str[-1]})
    else:
      split_str = 'null'


def CallUid():
      with open('hh', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
          CheckUid(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CallUid()
```

> result output:

```
$ ./function2.py
{'UserID': 'aashishp', 'MangerID': 'rpudota'}
{'UserID': 'abaillie', 'MangerID': 'davem'}
{'UserID': 'abishek', 'MangerID': 'kalyang'}
```

> Note: Please quote examples or point edition in code if you feel as
>   i'm just a newbie learner.

Comment: You should be intentional about what you return from a function. Instead of allowing the first function to fall off the end and return `None` by default, it would be better to explicitly return `{}` so that the return value is consistent. You could still capture the return value with `retval = CheckUid()` and test it: `if retval:`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, appreciate your expert advise, would be great if you quote example when you have time.

Comment: I'm not sure I have a concrete example, it's just a guiding principle that will make your code more consistent and easier to reason about. Many languages will enforce a consistent return strategy, such as C++ or Java.

Comment: The line `split_str = 'null'` doesn't do anything useful in either version of your function, since it returns immediately afterwards without doing anything with `split_str`. You need to decide what you want your code to do in that situation, and then write code to do it. Your current code returns `Null` by default if it takes the `else` branch, but you should be explicit if that's what you want.

Comment: @Blckknght, thats true i Just want to ignore that where user ID is the the `userid.txt` file but really not exixts in the LDAP database. but as you said we can do it better.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose if `if __name__ == '__main__':` is to allow you to either run your program from the command line and have it do something, or use it as a module without having it do anything.

With your example `function1.py`, if you wanted to use `CheckUid` from another file, it wouldn't be very useful: you could do

```
from function1 import CheckUid
userInfo = CheckUid('karn')
```

but you wouldn't get anything: `userInfo` would always be `None`, whether the user `karn` was found or not, and the function may have printed output that you might not want. But if you were to use `CheckUid` from `function2.py` instead, `userInfo` would be `None` only if the user *wasn't* found, and a dictionary if it was. So you almost always want to use the style from `function2.py` and return a value rather than printing it.

Since your function sometimes returns a dictionary and sometimes returns `None`, wherever you use it - in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` section or in another script - you'll need to check what you get back from it. For example, to skip printing `None` when a user is not found, you could modify your `function2.py` as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('hh', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            result = CheckUid(line.strip())
            if result:
                print(result)
```

Comment: Nathan, you raised a valid point of importing the function into another that's very important, thx for your detailed Answers , very appreciative. Though i have used a little diffent approach with the code geting the results tabulated  here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423452/4795853